# Is identical (===) in Twig

Tags: php, twig

Here's the PHP code:

```
if ($var===0) {do something}
```

It "does something" only when `$var` is actually 0 (and if `$var` is not set, it doesn't work, so everything is OK).

However, Twig doesn't support === operator, and if I write:

```
{% if var==0 %}do something{% endif %}
```

it "does something" all the time (even when `$var` is not set). In order to fix it, I wrote such a code:

```
{% if var matches 0 %}do something{% endif %}
```

Is it a proper way to do === comparison in Twig, or I did something wrong here? If it's wrong, how should it be fixed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `same as` in Twig for `===` comparisons:

```
{% set var1=0 %}
{% set var2='0' %}

{% if var1 is same as( 0 ) %}
    var1 is 0.
{% else %}
    var1 is not zero.
{% endif %}

{% if var2 is same as( 0 ) %}
    var2 is 0.
{% else %}
    var2 is not 0.
{% endif %}

{% if var2 is same as( '0' ) %}
    var2 is '0'.
{% else %}
    var2 is not '0'.
{% endif %}
```

Here is a twigfiddle showing it in operation:

https://twigfiddle.com/k09myb

[Here is the documentation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tests/sameas.html) for `same as` also stating that it is equivalent to `===`. Hope that helps you!

Comment: Thanks, this one is very useful

Answer (score 4):

Twig doesn't have `===` but it has `same as` instead. See: https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tests/sameas.html

So you could write:

```
{% if var is same as(0) %}do something{% endif %}
```

Eventually, you can use `is defined` to check whether the variable is set.

Comment: Thanks for the "same as". I was thinking about is defined too, but it would launch the code even when var value is "abc" for example.

Comment: Update - I found this code needs some fixing. If I use is same as(0) - it does NOT work. It only works when I change it to is same as('0') (in other words, quotes seem "a must" when 0 is used).

Comment: @MindaugasLi Then the problem is somewhere else in your code. The doc says: *"This is the equivalent to === in PHP"*. So if it works with `'0'` than you're comparing `var` to a string with a single `'0'` character which is very different to `0` integer (`0 === '0'` is always `false`). In other words, you assigned string `"0"` to `$var` somewhere where you think you're assigning an integer.

Comment: Thanks for follow up. The variable is actually assigned via OPTION input in form (where value 0 is used for Disabled and value 1 for Enabled)

Comment: Ok :), so you can try to force convert it to integer with intval() function... I guess